# Is it possible to save file locations in Visual Studio Code to navigate between folders?

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, directory, hyperlink, navigation

I have a Visual Studio Code project with lots of files in lots of subfolders. As I am working on my code I need to navigate back and forth through all of these different (sub-)locations which is very tedious. **Is there a way to save links to files to quickly access them?**

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl+P` and type part of the file name

Comment: yes I did but I am looking for something like a link to jump between folders

Comment: in the question you tell `links to files`, but now you want `jump between folders`, what needs to happen when you `jump between folders`

Comment: ... jump to a folder, open a file in that folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) you can create a file with relative paths to files and have a `Related Links` View in the Explorer bar. This View can be locked to the file with the links.

1. Create a file in the workspace root: `filelinks.txt`

   ```
   file: subdir1/file1.py
   file: subdir1/file2.py
   file: subdir2/file3.json
   file: subdir2/file4.xml
   ```

   You can add line numbers at the end of the filepath: `@123`
2. Add the following setting:

   ```
   "html-related-links.include": {
       "plaintext": [
         { "find": "file:\\s+((?!.*?@).+?)" },
         { "find": "file:\\s+((?=.*?@).+?)@(\\d+)", "lineNr": "$2" }
       ]
     }
   ```
3. When you view the file `filelinks.txt`, press the lock button in the `Related Links` View
4. When you add or remove files the view is updated.
5. You can close the editor for `filelinks.txt` when you have locked the file. When you want to change the list open `filelinks.txt` again.